# show all array before and after my index sign

Tags: php, arrays, nlp

Could you give me advice about this problem ?

The output is

```
word no  0  My = 
word no  1  brother = 
word no  2  see = Predicate
word no  3  the = 
word no  4  moon =
```

my question is how to sign word, if it before predicate it call subject and after predicate is object

```
word no  0  My is Subject
word no  1  brother is Subject
word no  2  see is Predicate
word no  3  the is Object
word no  4  moon is Object
```

This is my code

```
<?php
$a = "My brother see the moon";
$b = explode(" ",preg_replace("/(\.|\"|,|;|\(|\)|'|)+?/i","",$a));
for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
{
    $kata_kerja = 'see';
    $huruf_kecil = strtolower($a);
    $fungsi_replace = preg_replace("/(\.|\"|,|;|\(|\)|'|)+?/i","",$huruf_kecil);
    $pecah_untuk_kata = explode(" ",$fungsi_replace);
    $pecah_kata = $pecah_untuk_kata[$ulangKata];
    echo "kata ke - ".$ulangKata." ".$b[$ulangKata]."<br>"; 
}
echo "<br>";
for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
{
    echo $b[$ulangKata]."<br>";
}
echo "<br>";
for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
{
    $tmp = $ulangKata;
    if($b[$ulangKata]==$kata_kerja)
        {
            $name = 'Predicate';
            echo "word no-> ".$ulangKata." -> ".$b[$ulangKata]." = ".$name."<br>";
        }
else{echo "word no-> ".$ulangKata." -> ".$b[$ulangKata]." = <br>";}
}
?>
```

$text = "you were studying when she called"

output if I have 2 predicate

```
word no-> 0 -> you= Subject
word no-> 1 -> were= Subject
word no-> 2 -> studying= Predicate
word no-> 3 -> when= 
word no-> 4 -> she= subject
word no-> 5 -> called= predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

Output `Subject` untill `$b[$ulangKata]==$kata_kerja` then `Object`

```
$name='Subject';
for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
{
    if ($name == 'Predicate') $name = 'Object';
    elseif($b[$ulangKata]==$kata_kerja)  $name = 'Predicate';
    echo "word no-> ".$ulangKata." -> ".$b[$ulangKata]." = ".$name."\n";
}
```

output

```
word no-> 0 -> My = Subject
word no-> 1 -> brother = Subject
word no-> 2 -> see = Predicate
word no-> 3 -> the = Object
word no-> 4 -> moon = Object
```

Comment: It work's, but I have problem if There's 2 Predicate, How to handle it ?

Comment: i did not see that your code can to output two predicates. How do you think to save them?